# Are the following SQL querys troublesome or fine from performance perspective?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Can somebody tell me if the following query's are good or bad from performance perspective ?

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_index ON tbl_example(column1, column2)

SELECT ID, column1, column2
FROM tbl_example
WHERE column1 = @param1
AND   column2 = @param2

SELECT ID, column1, column2
FROM tbl_example
WHERE column2 = @param2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, neither query may be able to use the index.  In the first query, the `WHERE` clause can use the index.  However, in addition to `column1` and `column2`, you are also selecting `ID`.  The index does not include the `ID` value, which means that SQL Server would have to do a lookup on the clustered index to find that value.  Given the cost of such a lookup, the optimizer may choose to not use the index at all.

For the second query, the `WHERE` clause restricts using `column2`.  Unfortunately, `column2` does not form a leftmost portion of the index, so the index cannot be used in this query either.

Here is an example of query which should be able to use the index:

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM tbl_example
WHERE column1 = @param1
AND   column2 = @param2;
```

The following would also work:

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM tbl_example
WHERE column1 = @param1;
```

You could also stick with your very first query and instead include `ID` column in the leaf node of the index:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_index ON tbl_example(column1, column2) INCLUDE (ID)
```

This should make it possible for your original first query to use the index.

Comment: Thus all the searching & projection column will come on indexing ?

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin I don't understand your question.

Comment: in 2nd query  3 columns selected where except id all are in indexing and you suggest to include id on indexing so i am asking to you for better performance thus we need all searching & selection column have to include on  indexing

Comment: It depends on the query.  If the index doesn't cover all the columns being selected, then SQL Server might have to do another lookup, which can get to be costly.